# Save XAML file in database

Tags: silverlight, xaml, file, save

I have a Silverlight application in witch i can create presentation slides(like in PowerPoint), and i whant to save this slides(XAML and .cs files) in database or somwhere else, where i can be able to load and to use them.

Regard, 
Andrei.

Comment: Where and how to save my xaml and .cs file?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should compile the XAML and .CS files into Silverlight Class Libraries (DLLs)
2. Store the DLLs in your database
3. dynamically download the DLLs as needed

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.cuttingedge.aspx) and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434650.aspx) by Dino Esposito in MSDN Magazine.